# Why am I getting a "no method" error for a simple matrix add operation in Ruby? Many essentially identical lines in my other programs

Tags: ruby, matrix, methods, undefined

Here's the error statement:

> EvoWithout.rb:53:in `block (2 levels) in ': undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Here's line 53:

```
if behavior[i,0] > Thrsh && s == 0 then animal[i,0]+= 5 end
```

Here's the relevant code:

```
situation= Matrix[ [1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                   [1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1],
                   [1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1],
                   [1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1],
                   [1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1] ]
# Build brain with $Behavmax rows of 0,1's
brain = Matrix.build(10,16) { 1 }
for i in (0..$Behavmax)
    for j in (0..$Stimmax)
        if rand(4) < 1.1 then brain[i,j] = 0 end
    end # j
end #i
stimulus=Matrix.column_vector([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])
behavior=Matrix.row_vector([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])
animal=Matrix.row_vector([20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20]) # to hold value of fitness
# BEGIN MAIN PROGRAM
# Noise=20
# Go through once presenting 1 situation after another
for s in (0..4)
    for j in (0..$Stimmax)
        stimulus[j,0] = situation[s,j]
    end # for j
    # GENERATE BEHAVIOR
    behavior=brain*stimulus 
     for i in (0..$Behavmax) #fire iff stimulus pattern matches detector
        if behavior[i,0] > Thrsh && s == 0 then animal[i,0]+= 5 end
        #if behavior[i,0] > Thrsh && s != 0 then  print "Behavior#{i}=#{behavior[i,0]} and s=#{s}   " end
     end # for i
    puts
end # for s
```

Comment: `animal` matrix consists of one row, so `animal[1, 0] == nil`, that's probably why it happens.

Comment: Nope, that's not it.  Changing it to `animal[1]` gives this error:lib/ruby/2.6.0/matrix.rb:299:in `[]': wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2) (ArgumentError)

Comment: That's not the point. `animal[0, 0]` returns `20`, just as `animal[0, 1]` etc. It seems instead of `behavior[i, 0]` and `animal[i, 0]` you should have `behavior[0, i]` and `animal[0, i]`.

Comment: Ok, could be. but you'll note that I use `behavior[i,0]` and it works. Indeed, I copied behavior to make animal.  So no apparent reason why animal doesn't work.  But i'll try

Comment: Changing `animal[i,0]` to `animal[0,i]` does work.  Why that's different than behavior remains a mystery.  Thanks.

Comment: It's none of mystery. `animal` and `behavior` matrices contain only one row each, so if you want to iterate over its values you need to iterate over columns, not rows. `animal[i, 0]` iterates over rows. `animal[0, i]` iterates over columns.

Comment: I'm not sure what your code is supposed to do. However manual iteration is almost never needed. "Rubyfying" your code you might end up with something like [this](https://gist.github.com/3limin4t0r/6935cd10dfb86ca13b9d974711e40cf1). The should produce the same result, with the only difference that `stimulus` and `behavior` are not set after iteration. Since you completely replace them each iteration I thought this it wouldn't be necessary to leak the scope outside of the block.

Answer (score 1):

An important skill to learn is to read error messages and warnings. In your title, you ask:

> Why am I getting a “no method” error for a simple matrix add operation in Ruby?

But, that's *not* what the error message is saying!

You *don't* get a [`NoMethodError`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/NoMethodError.html) for a matrix add operation ([`Matrix#+`](https://rubydoc.info/stdlib/matrix/Matrix:%2B)). If you were, the error message would say something like:

```
EvoWithout.rb:53:in `block (2 levels) in ': undefined method `+' for animal:Matrix (NoMethodError)
```

Note that the error message would say (**bold** emphasis mine) "undefined method `+' for **animal:Matrix**" (which would be wrong, because `Matrix#+` exists). However, that's not what your error message is saying. Your error message says (**bold** emphasis mine):

> undefined method `+' for **nil:NilClass**

Which is correct, because [`NilClass`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/NilClass.html) does, in fact, *not* have a `+` method, and neither do its superclasses [`Object`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html), [`Kernel`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html), and [`BasicObject`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/BasicObject.html).

So, you are looking in the wrong place: your problem is not with the matrix add operation, your problem is that your matrix *index* operation returns `nil`.

And the reason for that is rather simple: you `animal` matrix contains only a single row, but you are iterating over `$Behavmax + 1` rows. So, as soon as `$Behavmax` is greater than zero, you will index into the second row of `animal`, which doesn't exist. Therefore, it will return `nil`, and your addition will fail.

Remember that `a ω= b` for any operator `ω` and arbitrary expressions `a` and `b` is equivalent to `a = a ω b` with `a` only evaluated once, so

```rb
animal[i,0]+= 5
```

is roughly equivalent to:

```rb
__temp__ = animal[i, 0]
animal[i, 0] = __temp__ + 5
```

And if `i` is anything other than `0`, `__temp__` will be `nil`, because there is only one row in `animal`.